# Allocating using malloc inside a function passing the address of the pointer and using vector syntax?

Tags: function, pointers, malloc

What's wrong on the code below? I need to send the address of the pointer *A to the function, read some numbers with scanf inside it, return to main and print the numbers read at that function.

```
void create_number_vector(int **number)
{
   (*number) = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<5; i++){
     scanf("%d",number[i]);
  }
}

int main(void){
    int i, *A;

    create_number_vector(&A);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Except one** line(concept), everything is pretty much OK.

Problamatic line is:

```
scanf("%d",number[i]);
```

And should be replace with:

```
scanf("%d", *number+i);
```

Because our allocated variable is a pointer, we should use him like that, we should go to the 'i' address inside of the allocated variable and scan into him.

Ofcourse you can keep on using the "array" style usage, with this syntax:

```
scanf("%d", &(*number)[i]);
```

**P.S**
Don't forget to free the allocated resources at the end of the usage, altough this kind of small program that exits at the end of the echoing, it's still a good practice to always free your resources at the end of its usage.

Comment: scanf needs a pointer to the integer to read into, so you need `&(*number)[i]` for your last example...